# Laravel Service Provider Class Not Found

Tags: php, laravel, service-provider

I am using Laravel 5.4 I am creating a Service Provider just for testing. My goal is create an instance of my TestClass and make it say Hello World in a Test Controller. I have successfully registered my service provider, but when I try to instantiate my TestClass I get a Class not found error.

config/app.php

```
Test\Providers\MyTest\TestServiceProvider::class,
```

TestServiceProvider.php

```
namespace Test\Providers\MyTest;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Test\Services\TestClass;

class TestServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {

    }
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind('Test\Services\TestClass', function ($app) {
          return new TestClass();
        });

    }
}
```

TestClass.php

```
namespace Test\Services;

class TestClass
{

    public function SayHi()
    {
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

TestController.php

```
...
use Test\Services\TestClass;
...

class TestController extends Controller
{
    public function serviceProviderTest()
    {
        $words = 'words';
        $testClass = new TestClass();
        $words = $testClass->SayHi();

        return view('test.serviceProviderTest', array(
            'words' => $words
        ));
    }
    ...
}
```

This gives me the following error:

> FatalThrowableError Class 'Test\Services\TestClass' not found

If I comment out

```
// $testClass = new TestClass();
// $words = $testClass->SayHi();
```

I get no errors and I see 'words' in my view as expected.

Why can't my TestClass be found?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Not sure about what the error is, but you're not actually using the object registered in the service provider in your controller. You'd need to do `app(TestClass::class)` instead of `new TestClass()`

Comment: @PhilCross does `app(TestClass::class)` need to be in the service provider or controller?

Comment: Controller. When you register classes in service providers, you're registering them with the `Container`. when you use the function `app()`, it's just a shortcut to grabbing things from inside the container.

Answer (score 3):

Add the new base path into your `composer.json`:

```
"psr-4": {
     "App\\": "app/",
     "Test\\": "test/"
 },
```

Then run:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Comment: That just bypasses the service provider.